# Sscanf() Function

Tags: c++, function

What is the difference between using '&' with year and day as an arguments and doesn't use it with month and weekday in sscanf() function ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int day, year;
char weekday[20], month[20], dtm[100];

strcpy( dtm, "Saturday March 25 1989" );
sscanf( dtm, "%s %s %d  %d", weekday, month, &day, &year );

printf("%s %d, %d = %s\n", month, day, year, weekday );

return(0);
}
```

Comment: `&` takes the address of the argument. With an array it's not necessary (in this case) because when you pass the name of an array to a function, what's actually passed is the address of the beginning of the array, even without the `&`.

Comment: Are you sure you are studying C++ and not C? These are two very different languages.

Comment: yes, i'm studying c++ but in some problems i need to use the c library

Comment: @JerryCoffin explains it well. I just wanted to add that you could also do &arr[0] to pass the array's address if you want to use &. In your case do &weekday[0] which means the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` operator gets the address of a variable. So you're actually passing a pointer to `day` and `year` into `sscanf`.

Since they are arrays, `weekday` and `month` are already pointers to their first elements.

So rather than passing in different things to `sscanf` you're actually passing in the same things.

2 `char*`s and 2 `int*`s.

Comment: I would think the dereferencing operator dereferences the variable, not the address-of operator.

Comment: @chris Good call. I don't know about others, but I'd certainly appreciate you editing the dumbness out of my posts when you catch it.